# Check if string contains only emojis - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, emoji

I want to check whether the string contains only emojis, it should not have alphabets, numbers or special character.

It is working fine with one emoji but for more then two emojis it is returning false, look at the code snippet.

```js
var emoji_regex = /^(?:[\u2700-\u27bf]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|[\u0023-\u0039]\ufe0f?\u20e3|\u3299|\u3297|\u303d|\u3030|\u24c2|\ud83c[\udd70-\udd71]|\ud83c[\udd7e-\udd7f]|\ud83c\udd8e|\ud83c[\udd91-\udd9a]|\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]|[\ud83c[\ude01-\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|[\ud83c[\ude32-\ude3a]|[\ud83c[\ude50-\ude51]|\u203c|\u2049|[\u25aa-\u25ab]|\u25b6|\u25c0|[\u25fb-\u25fe]|\u00a9|\u00ae|\u2122|\u2139|\ud83c\udc04|[\u2600-\u26FF]|\u2b05|\u2b06|\u2b07|\u2b1b|\u2b1c|\u2b50|\u2b55|\u231a|\u231b|\u2328|\u23cf|[\u23e9-\u23f3]|[\u23f8-\u23fa]|\ud83c\udccf|\u2934|\u2935|[\u2190-\u21ff])$/;

const emo_test = str => console.log(emoji_regex.test(str));

emo_test(""); //true
emo_test("hello"); //false
emo_test("9034"); //false
emo_test("$z5##"); //false
emo_test(""); //true
```

For the last one it only contains only emojis so should return `true` but it is returning `false` instead, any solution ?

Comment: Just add a `+` (one or more matches) after the group. `var emoji_regex = /^(?: .... )+$/;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add `+` or `*` before `$` in your regex. like the following.

```js
var emoji_regex = /^(?:[\u2700-\u27bf]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|[\u0023-\u0039]\ufe0f?\u20e3|\u3299|\u3297|\u303d|\u3030|\u24c2|\ud83c[\udd70-\udd71]|\ud83c[\udd7e-\udd7f]|\ud83c\udd8e|\ud83c[\udd91-\udd9a]|\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]|[\ud83c[\ude01-\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|[\ud83c[\ude32-\ude3a]|[\ud83c[\ude50-\ude51]|\u203c|\u2049|[\u25aa-\u25ab]|\u25b6|\u25c0|[\u25fb-\u25fe]|\u00a9|\u00ae|\u2122|\u2139|\ud83c\udc04|[\u2600-\u26FF]|\u2b05|\u2b06|\u2b07|\u2b1b|\u2b1c|\u2b50|\u2b55|\u231a|\u231b|\u2328|\u23cf|[\u23e9-\u23f3]|[\u23f8-\u23fa]|\ud83c\udccf|\u2934|\u2935|[\u2190-\u21ff])+$/;

const emo_test = str => console.log(emoji_regex.test(str));

emo_test(""); //true
emo_test("hello"); //false
emo_test("9034"); //false
emo_test("$z5##"); //false
emo_test(""); //true
```

Comment: There is a bug: `emo_test("[");` returns true, while false is expected